# Reference on SDE driven by jump processes

Tags: option-pricing

Are there reference on SDE driven by jump proccesses? e.g. Shepard-Nielson Model

Comment: What kind of a reference are you looking for? There's a lot of stuff on SDEs with jumps out there...

Comment: A book by Cont and Tankov, Financial Modelling with Jump Processes, might be useful.

Comment: @olaker just general theory? an introductory one would be good.

Comment: @Lost1 I added a book in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the original reference here but what about Merton's [Jump-Diffusion model](http://financelab.nctu.edu.tw/Students/chiu/jd.pdf)?

[Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-Time Models](http://www.amazon.de/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/0387401016/ref=pd_sim_eb_7) by Steven Shreve has some chapters about modelling with jump-processes. I think it is a slightly easier introduction to the topic than Cont/Tankov.